# Youtube Analytics API, return 500 videos, only metrics are returned?

Tags: google-api, analytics, youtube-analytics-api

With YouTube Analytics I can return a single YouTube video daily history from `start date` to `end date` with the below query:

```
https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel==$channel_id&metrics=views,likes,dislikes,comments,subscribersGained,averageViewDuration&dimensions=day&startDate=2019-09-20&endDate=2020-10-28&filters=video==$videoid
```

However the channel has 2500 videos. I can do this with the above query for a one video at a time but i'm trying to do 500 videos at a time.  I've read documentation and they allow multiple video id's.

```
$videoids = "$videoid1,$videoid2,$videoid3,$videoid4,$videoid5";

https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?ids=channel==$channel_id&metrics=views,likes,dislikes,comments,subscribersGained,averageViewDuration&dimensions=day&startDate=2019-09-20&endDate=2020-10-28&filters=video==$videoids
```

The problem is no video id is returned only the metrics.  I need the videoid to be returned so I can put the metric values into database, with relative video id.

How do i solve?

Comment: Why are you using == in a query string?   Did you try adding a dimensions of video id?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query  , check parameters: ids and filters